# Ubuntu won't boot: run-init: /sbin/init: Permission denied and /bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash

Tags: boot, command-line, 16.04, systemd, init

Last night everything was fine with my Ubuntu 16.04. Today I tried to turn it on and it simply won't boot, throwing these errors:

```
run-init: /sbin/init: Permission denied
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: /sbin/init: Permission denied
run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied
run-init: /bin/init: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash
```

- It does not give me any kind of shell
- I tried the recovery item in the GRUB menu, but the same error appears
- I also tried adding `systemd.unit=rescue.target` as a kernel parameter; it didn't work either.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in the messages you get, the most possible cause is a permission issue. Also it seems that `/sbin/init` and `/etc/init` exist but `/bin/init` does not.

---

#### Get rid of /bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash

First we should get a shell to fix the problem. To get rid of `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash` and get a shell: If you only have an Ubuntu installed (GRUB will not appear by default), while the system is booting hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key to make GRUB appear. Then on the default menu press <kbd>E</kbd>.

You will find a line starting with `Linux`. At that line remove the `splash` parameter and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, now you will be
 dropped into a `sh` shell. Run `/bin/bash` to get a bash shell if you want to. I prefer `bash` over `sh` because it has auto-complete functionality.

Alternatively instead of removing `splash` parameter, you can add `init=/bin/bash` at the end of that line and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>; this time we'll be dropped into `bash` instead of `sh`.

---

#### Fix the run-init: /sbin/init: Permission denied

Run:

```
ls -lH /sbin/init
```

It should produce something like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1577000 Feb 15 12:20 /sbin/init
```

As we can see permissions are messed up. in almost all systems these days `/sbin/init` is a link to `systemd`, just to make sure:

```
# ls -l /sbin/init
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1577000 Feb 15 12:20 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Sure it is, your `/` (root) file system is mounted in `ro` state (Read only), lets change it to `rw` (Read and write):

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then fix the permissions:

```
# chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Reboot the system.