# Ubuntu unable to start: run-init: /sbin/init: no such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, boot, init

I have Ubuntu16.04 LTS installed on my system. I upgraded MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6 by following  [this online documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7). The upgrade process seemed to be successful. But when I tried to execute my PHP page it did not get parsed. So I tried to restart my laptop but after that I am getting a `Recovering journal` screen at every boot with messages like these:

```
run-init: /sbin/init: no such file or directory
Run-init: /etc/init : permission denied
Run-init: /bin/init: no such file or directory
Mbibmsh: 0 : Can't open splash
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link of the documentation that you're talking about. What do you mean by 'upgradation seems to be successful'? Why are you not sure? If you can then please take a picture of the screen while those error messages are shown and attach that with your question so that people here can better understand the problem.

Comment: Successful means it did not thrown any error,  i just followed this documentation https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7 (first answer)  and iam unable to add image as i need at least 10 reputation to upload image please understand

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed. Are you getting errors like this: `run-init: /sbin/init: Permission denied
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: /sbin/init: Permission denied
run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied
run-init: /bin/init: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash`. If yes, then try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/912578/248467

Comment: i tried that too but no luck, actually mine case is different please look i edit my question to list some messages i get on my screen,in my case sbin/init is no such file or directory

Comment: Please guide me if i need to install the ubuntu again,if install again is an option than i do not have any issue

Comment: Did you follow the steps as mentioned by Ravexina? If yes then what output messages (or error messages in case of failure) did you get? If you prefer to re-install Ubuntu then what preferences do you have? Do you want to keep your data in `/` intact? Or do you want to format all of the drive and do a fresh install? If you want to keep your data then may I know the partition scheme of your hard disk. I know it is a lot of work and if you don't have much time and you do have back up of your data (or don't care about the data) then I would suggest a fresh install.

Comment: Data is not important for me.. Help me to install again..

Comment: I am assuming that Ubuntu is the only OS on your system. If yes then please see this: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1 It's a step by step guide to install Ubuntu on your system. If you don't understand something or need help while installing Ubuntu, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Download ubuntu iso file and make bootable disk through universal usb installer and follow the steps but i did not get screen for installing ubuntu instead i get the same screen...

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not much help. When you use that bootable disk, do you get the grub where it asks for what you want to do (like *Try Ubuntu* or *Install Ubuntu*)? If yes, then please select **Try Ubuntu** . Then connect to internet and open a command prompt. Type `sudo apt install init`. Then reboot your system and detach the bootable disk. Turn the system on and see if it boot this time.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your support and help,  now i am able to install ubuntu without any loss of data, i am very thankful to you, you are really a nice person who believe in helping others.. May god fulfil all your wishes ☺️☺️☺️

Comment: Sorry for figuring it out after making you wait for a long time. Someone with better understanding of the problem might have solved this earlier. But anyway happy to find that your problem has been solved. Thank you so much for your wishes but I don't think god has something to do with it ;-) :-P